# speech recognition from audio file instead of microphone

Tags: c#, .net, delphi, speech-recognition

How can I perform speech recognition on speech coming from an audio file (.mp3, wav) instead of the microphone ?

I want to be able to do that from C#.NET and Delphi.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**This article answers your question specifically:**

Using WAV File Input with SR Engines
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms717071(VS.85).aspx

See the following articles for general info:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163663.aspx

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speech_Application_Programming_Interface

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms723627(VS.85).aspx

Comment: Many links.  Five years ago.

Comment: @Shane: *Six* years ago.

Comment: But with all the open sourcing they might win back the community? This post might be valid in the future :thumbs up: